# Pseudo to SQL? All Records where FirstName & LastName Is duplicated but City is different?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I need to find all records that the FIRSTNAME is a duplicate and the LASTNAME is a duplicate but the city is different for the records where the names are duplicate.

So my data looks like this:

```
FirstName    LastName    CustomerFileLocation          City
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   Joe        Smith         c:\file1\File1.txt         Dallas
   Joe        Jones         c:\File2\File1.txt         New York
   Joe        Smith         c:\File3\File1.txt         New Mexico City
   Harry      Smith         c:\File4\File1.txt         Boca Raton
   Joe        Smith         c:\File3\File1.txt         Dallas
   Michael    Smith         c:\File1\File1.txt         Dallas
```

I want the query to return

```
   Joe        Smith         c:\file1\File1.txt         Dallas
   Joe        Smith         c:\File3\File1.txt         New Mexico City
```

I wrote the following to find the matching FirstName and LastName.  But I am not sure how to say "and City doesn't match"

```
SELECT        
   dbo.TblFileCache.FirstName, dbo.TblFileCache.LastName, 
   dbo.TblFileCache.ClaimFilePath, dbo.TblFileCache.Skip
FROM
   dbo.TblFileCache 
INNER JOIN
   (SELECT        
       FirstName, LastName, COUNT(*) AS CountOf
    FROM 
       dbo.TblFileCache AS tblFileCache_1
    GROUP BY 
       FirstName, LastName 
    HAVING         
       (COUNT(*) > 1)) AS dt ON dbo.TblFileCache.FirstName = dt.FirstName 
                             AND dbo.TblFileCache.LastName = dt.LastName
WHERE        
    (dbo.TblFileCache.Skip = 0)
ORDER BY 
    dbo.TblFileCache.FirstName, dbo.TblFileCache.LastName
```

Comment: Why does your query only return one row for "Dallas"?  There are two rows in the data.

Comment: Please explain more clearly. 1. First we can find all sets of rows where first aname appears more than once and last name appears more than once. But maybe you want all sets of rows where the *pair* (first name, last name) appears more than once? 2. Then do you want the rows from all those rows where the city is unique in the table? Or rows from each set that have a city unique to that set? 3. What about skip and ordering?

Comment: Re 2. Or maybe by "but the city is different for the records where the names are duplicate" you are just redundantly stating that among rows with the same name pair the cities can be different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get all the rows in your original data where one set of user names has multiple cities, you can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             min(city) over (partition by FirstName, LastName) as mincity,
             max(city) over (partition by FirstName, LastName) as maxcity
      from dbo.TblFileCache t
     ) t
where mincity <> maxcity;
```

If you want one row per city, you can do an aggregation on top of this:

```
select FirstName, LastName, min(CustomerFileLocation) as CustomerFileLocation, city
from (select t.*,
             min(city) over (partition by FirstName, LastName) as mincity,
             max(city) over (partition by FirstName, LastName) as maxcity
      from dbo.TblFileCache t
     ) t
where mincity <> maxcity
group by FirstName, LastName, City;
```